# Differences between appDelegate.h and appDelegate.m

Tags: objective-c, appdelegate

I am new to Objective-c 
,
what is the difference between appdelegate.h and appDelegate.m? What is the difference between .h and .m files in general?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concise description of how .h and .m files interact in objective c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619048/concise-description-of-how-h-and-m-files-interact-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.h files are headder files, while .m are implementation files.  Your headder files, in objective-c, typically contain the classes @interface section with all the instance variables, property declarations, and method prototypes.

Think of it like an outline of an essay.  It has all the bullet points, while the paper itself has all the content.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I figured that out after all.